# How to avoid redundant CDB symbols when using QtCreator

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2015, qt-creator, windbg

Here is how I have configured my CDB Path in QtC

```
srv*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
cache*R:\temp_KB\symbolcache
```

I have a Win 10 Windows Kit installed here

```
X:\Windows Kits\10\
```

When I debug in QtC I see the symbols cached on R (as expected), but also on

```
X:\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\sym
```

How can I avoid this, as it is consuming a lot of disk space? The sym directory gets pretty big.

Edit: One detail based on my comment below. It seems like only windows symbols are stored twice, the Qt library symbols I only see once in  `R:\temp_KB\symbolcache`, but `wkernelbase.pdb` is stored twice (`R:`, `..sym`).

--

Win 10 x64, QtC 4.02, Qt 5.6.1, MSVC2015

Comment: in windbg configure symbol path correctly or set **_NT_SYMBOL_PATH** environment variable

Comment: Tried. Still I see them twice, in my very case in `R:\temp_KB\symbolcache` and `x:\Window ....\x86\sym`. Interestingly I do not see any symbols in the path configured in `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH`. I would expect QtC to call the debugger with cmd line args as configured in QtC, still odd where the symbols in `sym` come from.

Comment: hm, you can use LSE to create a symbolic link/junction from R:\temp_KB\symbolcache to X:\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\sym, so that it makes no difference where Windbg saves them, now they are always stored on R: http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html

Comment: also crossed my mind, however still wondering why this is happening, and obviously nobody else has a similar problem. Thanks for your support.

Comment: I have no idea why you get this. try my workaround